# Creating Strimzi cluster on kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, strimzi

I followed below link to create strimzi cluster operator in k8s

https://medium.com/@sincysebastian/setup-kafka-with-debezium-using-strimzi-in-kubernetes-efd494642585

Downloaded strimzi 0.17.0 version and unzip it. I ran 
Kubectl apply -f apply install/cluster-operator . 
I am getting error "Detection of version failed" and it's socket connection timed out.

For work around I have added STRIMZI_KUBERNETES_VERSION in cluster-operator conf file .
Now I am getting "Detection of routes.openshift.io/ API failed . API Will be disabled".

I thought it network policy issue and added to allow all ports. Getting same errors.
...
egress:
- {}
ingress:
- {}

Can anyone please  help me out what I am missing here and how to make it strimzi with debezuim in k8s .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the Kubernetes deployment where you are installing Strimzi? Is it some minikube? AKS, on AWS, ... ? Which Kubernetes version?

Comment: We have osfi k8s cluster environment and Version is v1.15.9

Comment: I have no idea what exactly is "osfi" Kubernetes ditribution. But from the error it looks like the operator doesn't have access to the API server. The message ""Detection of routes.openshift.io/ API failed . API Will be disabled" is in general ok as long as you are not on OpenShift, so that should not be a problem. But it is hard to help without having the full logs etc.

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure about the error you are getting but installing Strimzi using Helm is painless, I never faced any installation crashes:

Below is for Kafka app:

```
helm install strimzi/strimzi-kafka-operator \
--name my-strimzi-release \
--namespace strimzi \
--version 0.15.0
```

Comment: Tried with helm. Set up has successfully completed. But I am getting Get https://xx.xx.x.x.:443/version /timeouts=32s: dial up tcp xx.xx.x.x:443 timeout.

Comment: helm flag --name is no more in helm version 3

Answer (score 0):

It's actually pretty simple. You can use Minikube as a test environment and run the following commands:

```sh
VERSION="0.21.1"
NAMESPACE="kafka"

# create and select a new namespace
kubectl create ns $NAMESPACE
kubectl config set-context --current --namespace="$NAMESPACE"

# deploy the Strimzi operator
curl -L https://github.com/strimzi/strimzi-kafka-operator/releases/download/$VERSION/strimzi-cluster-operator-$VERSION.yaml \
    | sed "s/namespace: .*/namespace: $NAMESPACE/g" | kubectl replace --force -f -

# deploy the Kafka cluster
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/strimzi/strimzi-kafka-operator/$VERSION/examples/kafka/kafka-persistent.yaml
```